# App Crash due to Location Client Illegal State

Tags: android, google-maps, location-client

I've got a basic app that uses Google Maps to place a custom marker on the last known location of the device.  The app crashes pretty frequently due to an Illegal State Exception thrown by the location client.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

This is usually caused when an Asynctask finishes and then calls an update to the map with new info but gets interrupted due to pausing the activity.  I've tried setting a simple boolean check to determine if the client is connected before attempting an update.

```
if (servicesConnected() && locClientConnected)  {
        loc = lClient.getLastLocation();
//code to draw circle
}
```

but this seems to have no effect on the ANR/crash so it executes while the activity is active but most not complete before this is called:

```
protected void onPause()    {
    lClient.disconnect();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Would it be good practice to remove the disconnect here and allow it to complete?  or would that even make a difference?  I'm hoping someone has ran into this issue with Location client.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Use Loaders instead of AsyncTask to avoid this behaviour.
2. Check activity state before draw

   ```
   void onPause(){
       allowDraw = false;
       ...
   }

   void onResume(){
       allowDraw  = true;
       ...
   }

   if (servicesConnected() && locClientConnected && allowDraw)  {
       loc = lClient.getLastLocation();
       //code to draw circle
   }
   ```
3. Use try catch block :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  simplest method is a try-catch block within the updateMap() method, I think.  I had previously implemented a try-catch within the asynctasks but that wasn't catching this issue.  alo thanks for showing me Loader class.  Never knew it existed :)